# Does this series converge to a rational function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the series $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!(z-k)^k}$$ Is there any domain of the complex plain where this series converges to a rational function?

Any hints will be appreciated

Comment: It appears that the sum will have poles at $k=1,2,\cdots$

Comment: So we can conclude it doesn't converge to a rational function on any domain $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb{C}$ which contains an infinite subset of $\Bbb{N}$